# SSIS Package Validation Error (excel source)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to run a DTS through Microsoft Visual Studio and I receive the following errors:

> Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)
>   
>   Error at Append Pocientos - Data Flow Task [Tabla Procentual - Excel Source [42]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
>   
>   Error at Append Pocientos - Data Flow Task [Tabla Procentual - Excel Source [42]]: Opening a rowset for "Porciento$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
>   
>   Error at Append Pocientos - Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Tabla Procentual - Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   
>   Error at Append Pocientos - Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>   
>   Error at Append Pocientos - Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
>   
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>   
>   
> ------------------------------
>   
> Program Location:
>   
>     at >Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

Comment: It literally tells you exactly what the error was... `Opening a rowset for "Porciento$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database. `.  Did you have a question that you wanted to ask?

Comment: I don't know what to do. I don't know anything about Data Transformation services, but was asked to help out. The object does exist. The file is placed where it is supposed to be placed. I do not know what to change in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS by default will use ” doublequotes as the quoted identifier if the OLE DB Provider does not override these settings.  Change SSIS OLE DB for SQLCommand and type “select * from dbo.table” instead of picking the table from the list.

When using Sybase OLE DB provider, run the Sybase Configuration Manager and change the data source to “Enable Quoted Identifiers” to True (1) to suppot ” doublequotes around the schema and table name.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrissk/2006/06/12/ssis-data-flow-task-an-ole-db-error-has-occurred-error-code-0x80040e37/